# jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: "success:" vs ".done"?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have been working with jQuery and AJAX for a few weeks now and I saw two different ways to 'continue' the script once the call has been made: `success:` and `.done`.

From the synopsis from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) we get:

> .done(): Description: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.
>
> success: (.ajax() option): A function to be called if the request succeeds.

So, both do something after the AJAX call has been completed/resolved. Can I use one or the other randomly? What is the difference and when one is used instead of the other?

Answer (score 505, accepted):

`success` has been the traditional name of the success callback in jQuery, defined as an option in the ajax call. However, since the implementation of `$.Deferreds` and more sophisticated callbacks, `done` is the preferred way to implement success callbacks, as it can be called on any `deferred`.

For example, success:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/',
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

For example, done:

```
$.ajax({url: '/'}).done(function(data) {});
```

The nice thing about `done` is that the return value of `$.ajax` is now a deferred promise that can be bound to anywhere else in your application. So let's say you want to make this ajax call from a few different places. Rather than passing in your success function as an option to the function that makes this ajax call, you can just have the function return `$.ajax` itself and bind your callbacks with `done`, `fail`, `then`, or whatever. Note that `always` is a callback that will run whether the request succeeds or fails. `done` will only be triggered on success.

For example:

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: showLoadingImgFn
  })
  .always(function() {
    // remove loading image maybe
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // handle request failures
  });

}

xhr_get('/index').done(function(data) {
  // do stuff with index data
});

xhr_get('/id').done(function(data) {
  // do stuff with id data
});
```

An important benefit of this in terms of maintainability is that you've wrapped your ajax mechanism in an application-specific function. If you decide you need your `$.ajax` call to operate differently in the future, or you use a different ajax method, or you move away from jQuery, you only have to change the `xhr_get` definition (being sure to return a promise or at least a `done` method, in the case of the example above). All the other references throughout the app can remain the same.

There are many more (much cooler) things you can do with `$.Deferred`, one of which is to use `pipe` to trigger a failure on an error reported by the server, even when the `$.ajax` request itself succeeds. For example:

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .pipe(function(data) {
    return data.responseCode != 200 ?
      $.Deferred().reject( data ) :
      data;
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    if ( data.responseCode )
      console.log( data.responseCode );
  });
}

xhr_get('/index').done(function(data) {
  // will not run if json returned from ajax has responseCode other than 200
});
```

Read more about `$.Deferred` here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

**NOTE**: As of jQuery 1.8, `pipe` has been deprecated in favor of using `then` in exactly the same way.

Comment: I wonder how the interactions of `success:`/`.done()` are defined, if at all. E.g. is `success:` just implemented as the first `.done()` these days?

Comment: You mean if you have both `success:` and `.done` on an ajax call? Good question. Since all other callbacks are called in the order that they're bound, my guess is yes, `success` is just called first.

Comment: Very nice post! Btw, in the pipe callback, shouldn't you be calling the pipe function with the jqXHR parameter in order to check for status response? 

Ex: .pipe(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if (jqXHR.status == 200) { ...

Comment: @Eder The scenario I'm addressing with this use of `pipe` is one where the request itself succeeds but the script on the server did not return what you were looking for. You may not want to throw an actual 404 or 500 or whatever on the server side because you want to meaningfully distinguish between http responses and application responses. Setting a response code in the JSON and then using `pipe` this way lets you handle different kinds of errors with more nuance.

Comment: Another important benefit of using promises is that your code becomes much more readable and you avoid 'callback hell'. This is espically true when you have multiple callbacks that you want to run each one after the previous finished. With promises it would look like myPromiseCall.then(..).then(..) instead of nested complicated structure of callbacks used with the success option.

Answer (score 5):

If you need `async: false` in your ajax, you should use `success` instead of `.done`. Else you better to use `.done`.
This is from [jQuery official site](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **As of jQuery 1.8,** the use of **async: false** with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you **must** use the **success/error/complete** callback options **instead of** the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as **jqXHR.done()**.

Comment: Who mention `async:false`?

Comment: `$.ajax({
   url: req_url, ...,
  async: false,
success: function (result, status, req) {
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            }
});`

Answer (score 2):

> **From [JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information). These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the `$.ajax()` request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.) Available Promise methods of the jqXHR object include:

```
jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
```

An alternative construct to the success callback option, refer to `deferred.done()` for implementation details.

```
jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

An alternative construct to the error callback option, the `.fail()` method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

```
jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
```

(added in jQuery 1.6)
An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the `.always()` method replaces the deprecated `.complete()` method.

In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the same as those of `.done()`: data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For failed requests the arguments are the same as those of `.fail()`: the jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to `deferred.always()` for implementation details.

```
jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

Incorporates the functionality of the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods, allowing (as of jQuery 1.8) the underlying Promise to be manipulated. Refer to deferred`.then()` for implementation details.

> **Deprecation Notice:** The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use
>   `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.