# ajax call inside ajax success jquery then ajaxstart function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call(call 2) inside another ajax success function(call 1). Also i have an ajaxstart function which shows a loading image. But the problem is ajaxstart function is not working on the second ajax call(call 2)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: objParam,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: objParam,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {                     
            },     
            error: function(err) {
                alert("Please Try again");
            }
        });
    }, 
    error: function(err) {
        alert("Please Try again");
    }
});
```

Comment: does first ajax returns success ?

Comment: yes. both ajax runs fine. but ajaxstart function not working

Comment: Good practice is if you have inside another ajax to be outside into function, because ajax is asynchronous

Comment: actually im using another function inside the first ajax call. for demo purpose i have put that here :)

Comment: Show me all your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax Request inside Ajax Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089447/jquery-ajax-request-inside-ajax-request)

Comment: as per the documentation of `ajaxStart` - `Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins` [**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/)

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `.ajaxSend()` instead. Your accepted answer doesn't make much sense

Comment: no. that worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $.ajax or $.ajaxSetup is called with the global option set to false the $.ajaxStart () method will not fire

Try global:false inside $.ajax. It will work.