# passing the parameter in post in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass the response data to another page in ajax success.

I'm using jquery in laravel. I have called the function and get the data from the controller in success call. I want to pass the received data to another page detail

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'am_detailed_report', //send the request to the controller
  data: {
    am_geo_selection: am_geo_selection
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $url = "am_detailed?filter=" + data;
    window.open($url, "_blank"); //want to send the parameter in post instead of passing it in url.
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: why do you need this behavior? Looks like you will show some details using the filter, which GET should be appropriate for this

Comment: may be this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089447/jquery-ajax-request-inside-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'am_detailed_report', //send the request to the controller
  data: {
    am_geo_selection: am_geo_selection
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $url = "am_detailed"
    const html = `<form action="${url}" method="post">
      <textarea name="filter">${data}</textarea>
      </form>`
    const w = window.open("", "_blank"); 
    w.document.write(html);
    w.document.close();
    w.document.querySelector("form").submit()
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
  }
});
```