# $.ajax Deferred object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

These two codes (1)(2) seems to work in the same manner to me.

My questions are:
1) Are these two codes equivalent?
2) If yes why? If not what should I prefer and why?

---

(1)

```
$.ajax({
    url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
    success: callback,
    done: function () {
        // some code
    }
});
```

---

(2)

```
$.ajax({
    url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
    success: callback
}).done(function () {
    // some code
});
```

Comment: This post might serve you with some good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-diffrence-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two codes are equivalent, except that (by mistake?) you've left `success: callback` in the latter.

However IMHO the latter is preferred as deferred objects are far more flexible than supplying a callback directly to `$.ajax`.

In particular, using deferred objects allows for much better separation of logic and responsibility between initiating the AJAX call and the processing of the results of that call.  Also, some of the AJAX helper functions don't support an `error` callback.  If I write:

```
function doAjax() {
    return $.get(...);
}
```

I can then attach arbitrary numbers of `done` and `fail` handlers to the *result* of that function call, without ever having to pass those handlers into the `doAjax` function.

I can also combine the returned `promise()` object with other promises using `$.when()`, `$.pipe()`, etc, for very powerful synchronisation between multiple asynchronous events (including other AJAX calls, timers, animations, etc).  I *can't* do that using `success:`

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. Actually related to your reply I opened another question [How to spy jQuery AJAX request with Jasmine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088029/how-to-spy-jquery-ajax-request-with-jasmine). Could you give a look, thanks.