# How to spy jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

The following two ways of implementing an ajaxRequest (1) (2) should be equivalent.
Having said that:

1. Why does the unit test (3) that verifies the callback was executed, succeeds in (1) and fails in (2)?
2. How should I rewrite the test (3) to spy on the success callback in (2)?
3. If I try to  `stub jQuery.ajax` using sinon and the code (2) I get an error. How should I fix it?

Please, see the comments in code (3) for more details.

---

(1)

```
ajaxRequest: function (message, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            message: message
        },
        success: callback
    });
}
```

---

(2)

```
ajaxRequest: function (message, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            message: message
        }
    }).success(callback);
}
```

---

(3)

```
it("should execute the callback function on success", function () {
    spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(options) {
        options.success();
    }); // If I use the code (2) I get the following error
        // TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'success'
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
    ajaxRequest('some message', callback);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

(4)

```
it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
    sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax');
    backendController.ajaxRequest('some message', sinon.spy()); 
    // Cannot call method 'success' of undefined
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a walkthrough:

If you use the code in number 2, you are invoking the ajax function on jquery:

```
return $.ajax({
  url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    message: message
  }
...
```

after calling this function with those parameters, jQuery returns a [jqHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that happens to have a success function defined.  That success function is then invoked:

```
...
}).success(callback);
```

All is well so far until your jasmine test spies on the ajax function.  The same options you used to invoke `$.ajax` are passed to this new spy.

```
// this is the value of the options parameter
{
    url: backendRouter.generate('feedback_send'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        message: message
    }
}
```

When this object is passed, your fake function actually attempts to call `options.success`, which does not exist!  Hence the error.

Comment: +1 thanks for your walkthrough. Actually now I would like to write a test (3) in order to run it on the code (2). Do you have some idea how to make it? I updated my question. thanks.

Comment: Apparently, the .success() call will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
I suggest that instead of using jasmine to mock the ajax method that you look at sinon.js (http://sinonjs.org/) that will actually mock your browser's native XHR.  It works great for me.

Comment: I tried to `stub jQuery.ajax`, see my question, the code (4). And I get and error, why? which example of `sinonjs.org`should I get?

Comment: Yes, you can use sinon to stub jquery's functions, but that's the same thing as jasmine's spyOn.  What's particularly interesting about sinon is that you can fake XHR's and "fake server": http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server, try that approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery plugin that uses `sinonjs` with `qunit` and provides a much easier way to write ajax tests and get expected results.

Take a look at **[jqueryspy](https://github.com/inspiraller/jqueryspy/blob/master/README.md)**