# AJAX within AJAX not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on social site. On first load, it fetches all the post, each with two comment max. If the comments are more than two
it attach `More comment` button to it, if clicked, it displays all the comments and replace the button with `Less comment`.

That is just a little story of how it works. I want whenever a comment is made, it should be appended to existing ones and displayed instantly via
AJAX. It does this but it redisplay each comments 3 times, when you reload the page, everything is okay...

```
<div class = 'post_updates'>
  <div class = 'feeds'>
    <div class = 'commentdiv'>
       <textarea autocomplete = 'off' class='commenttext form-control' rows = '1'
       placeholder='Have your say...'></textarea>
       <button class='comment btn btn-xs btn-primary onespacedown' value = '7'
        type='submit'>Comment</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery AJAX code:

```
 $('.feeds').on('click', '.comment', function () {
var $this = $(this);
var post_comment = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val();
var post_id = $(this).val();
var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
var request = $.ajax({
      url: "insert.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id, comment: post_comment },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {    
        $pc = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.per_comment');
        //fetch comments and display
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "comments.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    post: post_id,
                    user: user_id
                },
                dataType: "html"
            });
            request.done(function (msg) {
                $pc.html(msg).data('loaded', true);
                $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments btn-block pullcomments' value='' name = 'more' type='submit'>Less comments</button>"); 
                $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val('');
        });
    });
})
```

In advance, thanks.

Comment: @Tats_innit: [jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: “success:” vs “.done”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8840257/1438393)

Comment: @Tats_innit `success` is the same as `done`...

Comment: Agreed @AmalMurali I missed the second call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax

Comment: @user3009875 yep, infact `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax

Comment: Is your php script returning the data properly? What is the append code like (the js that actually manipulates the DOM)?

Comment: The second AJAX call does the appending... And, the PHP code is working just fine.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to show what the second ajax call returns. Also, it places that html into the element with the "per_comment" class, but I see no such element in the code.

Comment: It may not be causing you any issues, but everywhere you call `.parents()`, you should probably be calling `.closest()` instead. The former could match more than one element, while the latter never will.

Answer (score 0):

try $.post in jquery

```
$.post("insert.php",{post : post_id , user : user_id, comment: post_comment},function(){})
.success(function(data){
    //callback when first post completed
    //begin second ajax post
    $.post("comments.php",{post: post_id,user: user_id},function(){})
    .success(function(){
        //call back when second post completed
    });
});
```