# JQuery .post() ajax parameters explanation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question about the JQuery .post() function for making ajax calls. The question is in the code below:

```
$.post( "processOrder", $( "#OrderForm" ).serialize(), function() {
          // What is the diff between putting code here....
        })
            .done(function(data) {

               // ... and putting it in the "done" instead ?.... 

              })
            .fail(function() {

              })
            .always(function() {

        });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14754681/1049184 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829

Answer (score 1):

Both will only fire if the request is deemed successful and they both pass the same arguments to the callback (data, textStatus, jqXHR). The only difference is `.done()` is attached in the "promise" style and uses jQuery's [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) implementation, whereas the other is passed as an argument to `$.post`.

You might consider the `.done()` method more flexible because you can return or pass the jQuery object elsewhere allowing other code to add a `.done()` or other deferred handler. That said, you can still use the success handler as an argument and then add a `.done()` later. Finally, `.done()` can accept an array of callbacks, all of which will be executed, whereas the success argument only accepts a single function.