# JQuery ajax success fired twice, because of .done callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some legacy code, which aborts ajax requests in a scenario & then after user-response, resends that request.

```
function resendLastAjaxRequest(ajaxRequest, ajaxSettings){
    if(ajaxSettings != undefined){
        $.ajax(ajaxSettings).done(function ( data ) {
            ajaxSettings.success(data);
        });
    }
```

Now, the above code fires the success handler for the request twice, but's its been there for more than a year & no one encountered it. Is it because of jquery version updates. We're currently using 2.0.3 
I don't know when exactly was jquery updated, but may be in earlier versions `done` was fired instead of `success`.
Did some digging but couldn't find any reason why it might have worked for so long, please help.

**Update**

[what is difference between success and .done() method of $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax)

It contains a comment saying

> ok, it's jQuery 1.8 :) Since $.ajax return a promise from jQuery 1.5
>   this is a simple substitution for a matter of consistency (using the
>   interface of deferred): done() take place of success(), fail() for
>   error() and always() for complete()

that means if `done` is called, then we have to trigger `success` explicitly. This might be the reason why it worked for so long. But now, before the done fires the `success` handler is already called & then the `done` callback calls the `success` handler again.

Any suggestions on how to change/modify the code such that `success` is called only once ?

EDIT

ajaxSettings looks like this :

```
accepts: Object
async: true
cache: false
complete: function (request, status)
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: Object
converters: Object
crossDomain: false
dataTypes: Array[1]
error: function (request, status){flatOptions: Object global: true hasContent: false isLocal: false jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: function (){var e=hn.pop()||x.expando+"_"+Yt++;return this[e]=!0,e}loadingdisplay: trueprocessData: true
responseFields: Object
success: function (htmlData) {type: "GET"
```

Comment: can you show your `ajaxSettings` object

Comment: I don't know for the old jQuery version but it seems to be the good behaviour now. You have a method 'success' in the object you pass to the ajax call, so this method will be invoked as a callback when the ajax request will succeed. And in the .done promise you also invoke this success method. You need to choose just one of them to make it works fine.

Comment: @OxyDesign yes, that's the fix but I'm more concerned about, how did it worked so long ?

Comment: What was the previous version used before you changed for 2.0.3 ?

Comment: trying to find out...

Comment: If it's below the **1.5**, I think `.done()` wasn't implemented, so the `success` method is invoked as a callback then `.done` throw an error in the console without breaking anything (like _"undefined is not a function"_). So in this case, you have an error in the console and only one callback function called.

Comment: With 1.4.4, http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/1jmL9282/ : 1 error in the console (because of `.done()`) and only 1 callback (`success` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, I think previously you had a **jQuery** version **lower than 1.5** (without `.done()` implemented) so the success method is invoked as a callback then `.done()` throw an error in the console without breaking anything (like `undefined is not a function`). So in this case, you have an error in the console and only one callback function called.

Demo with **jQuery 1.4.4** : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/1jmL9282/)

In the console :

> **1 error** : `undefined is not a function` (because of `.done()`)

and

> **1 log** : `Object` (datas from the call)