# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and using a little old tutorial on `node.js` that uses this snippet :

```
$(function () {    
    var roomId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/rooms"
    }).success(function (rooms) { 
        roomId = rooms[0].id;
        getMessages();
        $.each(rooms, function (key, room) {
            var a = '<a href="#" data-room-id="' + room.id + '" class="room list-group-item">' + room.name + '</a>';
            $("#rooms").append(a);
        });

    });

    [...]       

});
```

However I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function

at `}).success(function (rooms) {`

I'm wondering what can be wrong here?

Comment: You're looking for `done()`. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: Right. I replaced all `success` with `done` and the error is gone. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The call to ajax should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/rooms",
    success: function (rooms) { 

    }
});
```

You don't method chain the success function, it is one of the entries in the dictionary argument.

Comment: You can chain the success function call, but you need to use .done() shown in example @ https://jsfiddle.net/f7h8heb5/, but you are also add the success option in the ajax call as you example shows as well

Comment: Right, In jQuery 1.8 on the jqXHR object (returned by $.ajax) success is being replaced with done, error with fail and complete with always.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8847853/5774375

Answer (score 42):

Your code is correct there is no problem with it

but you might be including the new jquery library which doesn't allow .success() method

for newer version of jquery use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/rooms",
        success: function (rooms) {

        }
    });
</script>
```

and if you are using old jquery the .success() method would run without any problem

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({

        url: "/api/rooms",
        method: "GET",
        data: {'datavar': datavalue}

    }).success(function (rooms) {

        console.log("successfully run ajax request..." + rooms);

    }).done(function () {

        console.log("I am from done function");

    }).fail(function () {

        console.log("I am from fail function.");

    }).always(function () {

        console.log("I am from always function");

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 22):

According to the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0.
>
> You can use `jqXHR.done()`,  `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

---

These methods were originally added to jQuery's `$.ajax` as options callbacks, to be used like this

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'mypage.php',
    success  : function() { ... },
    error    : function() { ... },
    complete : function() { ... }
});
```

However, due to some confusion among users, they were later also accompanied by chainable methods with the same names

```
$.ajax().success(  function() { ... })
        .error(    function() { ... })
        .complete( function() { ... })
```

These methods have been deprecated since jQuery 1.8, and completely removed in jQuery 3.0, due to the use of Deferred objects, and later promises.

The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` are superseeded by the chainable `jqXHR.done()`,  `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` methods, the options callbacks are still available for now.

As of jQuery 3.0, jQuery's Deferred objects [are also Promise/A+ compliant](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible), which means they are "thenable", and can be used with `then()` as well

```
$.ajax("/status").then(function(data) {

}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

Comment: For my money, this is the best answer.  Thank you for being so complete.