# VUEJS TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

I want connect Vuejs with Local Payment Gateway,

add plugin on index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="https://staging.doku.com/doku-js/assets/js/payment.js?version=<?php echo time()?>"></script> <!-- To prevent js caching -->
<link href="https://staging.doku.com/doku-js/assets/css/doku.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

here below my methods

```
showPaymentPage() {
  post("payment/credit-card", {
    amount: this.amount+'.00',
    invoice: this.invoiceNumber,
    currency: 360
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        console.log(res.data);
        // this.payment = res.data.message
        const data = new Object();
            data.req_merchant_code = res.data.data.mallid; //mall id or merchant id
            data.req_chain_merchant = 'NA'; //chain merchant id
            data.req_payment_channel = '15'; //payment channel
            data.req_transaction_id = res.data.data.invoice; //invoice no
            data.req_amount = res.data.data.amount;
            data.req_currency = res.data.data.currency; //360 for IDR
            data.req_words = res.data.words; //your merchant unique key
            data.req_session_id = new Date().getTime(); //your server timestamp
            data.req_form_type = 'full';
            data.req_customer_id = this.$store.getters.getUser.id;

            getForm(data);
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

but get response on console log like below

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function
at getForm (payment.js?version=1579060503:1)
at app.js:35908
```

Please help me,

Comment: where you define axios?

Comment: hi @JinalSomaiya on same file.vue

Comment: please add it in question.

Comment: please include the whole necessary code like where the `$.ajax` is and `getForm`

Comment: hi @KarmaBlackshaw
$.ajax and getForm on this url <script src="https://staging.doku.com/doku-js/assets/js/payment.js?version=<?php echo time()?>"></script> <!-- To prevent js caching -->

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042085/uncaught-typeerror-ajax-success-is-not-a-function) can solve the problem.

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw do you have suggest for me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is no success function defined. Just bear in mind that jquery does not use promises, meaning you can not do `.then`/`.catch`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct there is no problem with it but with jQuery's recent update, `.success()` method is no longer allowed so the code below will emit an error.

```
$.ajax(url).success
```

For newer version of jquery, you can do:

```
$.ajax(url, {
  success: () => {
    // Do something
  }
})
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url,
  success: function () { 
    // Do something
  }
})
```

Or, you can simple use chain method like so:

```
$.ajax(url).then(x => {
  // Do something
})
```

Or

```
$.ajax(url).done(x => {
  // Do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function ajax().success.
You Can use something like this :

```html
$.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php",  
      success: function(data) {
         return data; 
      }
   });
```