# Load two divs with a single AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to use load() to load two divs `#follow-x` and `#follow-y` ajaxly with a click of a button.This is what I have tried in `success` function,but doesn't work,but works if I remove one of the function,so it loads only one div but I want it to load both.Thanks in advance

```
$('#follow').click(function(){

          $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{% url 'follow_class' %}",
                   data: {'pk': '{{class.pk}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(){
                       $('#follow-x').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-x");}
                       function(){
                       $('#follow-y').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-y");}

              }); 
        });
</script>
```

Dont mind the tags`{}` I'm using Django

Comment: Why have two separate functions? Why not just do `$('#follow-x').load(...); $('#follow-y').load(...);`?

Comment: the syntax of your code doesn't look correct. mainly, the closing `}` on your first load and the random unnamed and uncalled `function () {` wrapping your second .load. however, surely it would be better to just use $.ajax then extract the two divs from the response rather than sending two and doing the same for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only the first function is being called on `success`

put both statements in one function

```
$('#follow').click(function(){

          $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{% url 'follow_class' %}",
                   data: {'pk': '{{class.pk}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(){
                       $('#follow-x').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-x");                        
                       $('#follow-y').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-y");
                    }

              }); 
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your second load call is in another function *that never gets called*

```
$('#follow').click(function(){

          $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{% url 'follow_class' %}",
                   data: {'pk': '{{class.pk}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(){
                       $('#follow-x').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-x");
                       $('#follow-y').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-y");
                   }

              }); 
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Success is a property of the object passed to AJAX. In your code you attempt to assign it to a function containing the `follow-x` code, however a syntax error  is produced due to the next function statement that violates the obj structure. Try this.

```
success: function(){
     $('#follow-x').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-x");
     $('#follow-y').load("{% url 'class_details' %} #follow-y");
}
```

Also consider using the done callback instead of success. More info on that here [what is difference between success and .done() method of $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax)