# Making one ajax call when another executes successfully

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make another ajax call when one is executed successfully to pass the post variable to another controller action. However, it is returning null when I check the console log message. I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
$('#modify-store-name').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/user/get-one-store",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
          store_name: $(this).val()
     }
  }).done(function (msg) {
      $.each(msg, function (i) {
          $('#modify-store-label').attr('style', '');
          $('#modify-store-desc').attr('style', '');
          $('#modify-store-category-label').attr('style', '');
          $('#modify-store-category').attr('style', '');
          $('.upload-btn-wrapper').attr('style', '');

          $('#modify-store-desc').val(msg[i].store_description);
          $('#modify-store-category').html($("<option />").val(msg[i].store_category).text(msg[i].store_category));

          $('#msubmit').attr('disabled', false);
     });

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/user/modify-store",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            store_name2: $('#modify-store-name').val() // why is this sending a null value
        }
     }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
     }).fail(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
     });
   }).fail(function (msg) {
     $("#msg").html(msg.failure);
   });
});
```

and my php code:

```
public function getonestoreAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    try {
        $store_name = $this->params()->fromPost('store_name');

        echo  json_encode($this->getUserService()->getAStore($store_name));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo json_encode(array('failure' => $e->getMessage()));
    }

    return $view_model;
}

public function modifystoreAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        try {
            $store_name = $this->params()->fromPost('store-name2');
            echo json_encode($store_name); // returning null
            $mstore_name = $this->params()->fromPost('modify-store-name');
            $mstore_description = $this->params()->fromPost('modify-store-description');
            $mstore_category = $this->params()->fromPost('modify-store-category');
            $mstore_image = $this->params()->fromFiles('modify-store-image');

            if (count($mstore_image) > 0) {
                if ($this->getUserService()->modifyStore($store_name, array('store_name' => $mstore_name, 'store_description' => $mstore_description, 'store_category' => $mstore_category, 'store_image' => $mstore_image, 'tmp_name' => $mstore_image['tmp_name']))) {
                    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'Store was modified successfully.'));
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('failure' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    return $view_model;
}
```

I read that you can make two ajax calls like this but I'm not sure why one is not passing the store name via post.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: run the ajax you want inside the success function of another ajax call

Comment: Would that be the done function? Isn't that the success function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax/8847853

Comment: Yes, done is the success, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In second ajax call I try to get $('#modify-store-name').val() it's working.  Where you are sending modify-store-description, modify-store-category, modify-store-image etc in second ajax call?

Comment: in the second ajax call I am trying to send the store name's value to another action.

Comment: but it is passing a null value.

Comment: oh wow, nevermind, i had the wrong variable... that's embarrassing...