# Benefit to using jquery's .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: “success:” vs “.done”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done)

Is there any benefit to using jquery's done method compared to the success callback ?  As far as I can tell these would both execute similar (if not the same?)

Case 1 using `$.get` callback

```
$.get("....", function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Case 2 using .done()

```
$.get("....").done(function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach any number of handler before or after it's processed and count on them all firing.  You don't have to squeeze everything into a single function.

```
var request = $.get("....")
request.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
request.done(function(data) {
    // do something else
});
request.done(someOtherPredefinedFunction);
```

Besides, I believe the `success` handler is deprecated and scheduled for eventual removal.