# Smooth slide down animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've build a little function but it's not a smooth animation its lagging ... I've use it for a 1600x700pixel div on page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').slideDown(500);
});
```

Is there any solution to make it smooth on page load anyway how big or small the div is?

FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T8vkA/)

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830810/jquery-slidedown-animation-lag

Comment: Can you provide an jsfiddle？

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T8vkA/ here... look at it in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to try jQuery Easing plugin.

here is the Demos and download link: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

You can use it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').slideDown(500, "easeOutQuart");
});
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8vkA/1/