# importing csv using Ajax and PHP import csv to mysql, not uploading a file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have followin pages

- index.php
- importdata.php

Im trying to use ajax importing a csv file into MySql
I used dsome exapmples on the net but still wont work
index.php

the Script file in the beginning:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#but_import").click(function() {
        var formData = new FormData($("#import_form"));     
            $.ajax({
                url:"importData.php",
                data:formData,
                type:'POST',
                success:function(response) 
                {
                    var resp = $.trim(response);
                    $("#output").html(resp);
                }else[

                    $("#output").html("Error");

                });

    });
   });
```

The HTML after the script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Import CSV file data to the MySQL using PHP</title>

</head>
<body>
 <form id="import_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <table width="100%">

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 58px">
                    <input type='file' name="score_file" id="score_file">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >
                <input type="button" id="but_import" name="but_import" value="Import File"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>


<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="output">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Here is the HTML Part Sorry

Comment: which side is not working the server or ?

Comment: Maybe it's data formatting. Try this `new FormData($('#import_form')[0])`. And maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: Im have trouble passing the form infromation to the importData.php form.Not 100% sure if the ajax format is correctr. im a noob to this.

Comment: I had a look at the post. Im actully trying to import data from csv file to mysql using the ajax call. I dont want to refresh the page. I previously manage to get queries back using the format. but now stuck on passing the filename to import from index.php to the importdata.php using the ajax call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Your curly braces and brackets are wildly wrong, it seems. Try fixing those.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get information posted now doing the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#but_import").click(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('score_file')[0]);        



    alert(formData);    


        $.ajax({
             url: 'importData.php',
               data: formData,
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: false, 
                 processData: false,                
                 success:function(response) {
                        var resp = $.trim(response);
                        $("#message").html("yes");

                        }
        });

});

});
```

Bit now on the php form Im receiving following error
 Undefined index: score_file in importData.php on line 6

This is the inputbox in html file

```
<form id="import_form" name ="import_form" method="post" action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <table width="100%">

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 58px">
                    <input type='file' name="score_file" id="score_file">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >
                <input type="button" id="but_import" name="but_import" value="Import File"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

and the first 2 line of php file

```
 $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
if(!empty($_FILES['score_file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['score_file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
```

The error is on the 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

What error does it put out.

Also look at the spelling of "importdata.php".

In the ajax you have "url:"importData.php"" but at the start you said you have "importdata.php".

Comment: Sorry yes. spelling is correct. i typed incorrect when doing the post. I do notreceive any errors. nothing happen at all

Comment: Also please revise the function being called on success. Look at the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851839/add-if-else-function-in-ajax-jquery-function