# Returning XML file contents using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-io

I want to read the contents of a local file using JavaScript/jQuery.  I understand this is often discussed, but my example is a little different because I want to return the contents after the fetch is done rather than manipulate HTML.

I don't want to talk about security issues and local files because this code is meant to run within my own browser (Chrome, which I start with the --allow-file-access-from-files flag).

I have the following function to get the data...

```
function readData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        async: false, // this does not change the outcome
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            // Got the data, find entries and return them.
            console.log("Returning data");
            var doc = $(xml).find('entry');
            // This is where most examples manipulate dom, I want to
            // return the data instead
            return doc;
        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to do...

```
var xmlDoc = readData();
// undefined, why?
```

and have the document in the variable.  Instead I get undefined.  It seems that the function returns before the file is fetched.  Or maybe I have a problem with variable scope?

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  Yes, I am sure I want to use JavaScript even though I am doing this locally.

Comment: the problem here is readData is not returning any value, your success function is. I'm not sure its possible to do this with the structure of the ajax/callback model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stackoverflow answer regarding handling of $.ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done) has a good example of a nice way this can be used. This example can be slightly modified to give you something close to what you are looking for.

```
function xhr_get(url) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    beforeSend: showLoadingImgFn
  })
  .always(function() {
    // remove loading image maybe
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // handle request failures
  });

}
```

The examples of implantation of the above method is:

```
xhr_get('/index').done(function(data) {
  // do stuff with index data
});

xhr_get('/id').done(function(data) {
  // do stuff with id data
});
```

You might want to something like:

```
function readData() {
    var returnData;

    xhr_get('data.xml').done(function(data) {
        returnData = data;
    });

    return returnData;

}
```

Hope that helps.