# AJAX: loading HTML, CSS Links not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, post

Performing a basic AJAX request, but when the HTML is displayed no HTML links work and now CSS:hover elements work either.

Confused as to what I've done wrong. Here's an example of the code below.

CSS:

```
li:hover{ background:red; }
a{ text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{ text-decoration:underline; }
```

HTML (index.php):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    ajax();
});
</script>
<ul class="loadhere"></uL>
```

loadthis.php:

```
<li><a href="">Example</a></li>
```

JS (AJAX):

```
function ajax(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://example.com/loadthis.php",
    dataType: "html" 
})
.done(function(result){
    $('ul.loadhere').html(result);      
});
}
```

Comment: How looks like 'result'?

Comment: possibly the paths are relative to the example.com/loadthis.php - so it can't find the css file. You can change the paths to absolute, so for the CSS for example: http://example.com/css/style.css

Comment: If you take ajax out of the question for now and just add an `<li>` to the list does the CSS work for that?

Comment: The provided code works - http://jsfiddle.net/3WBbn/

Comment: As @Andreas said, this should work... unless you are cross-domain!

Comment: @AlexThomas Yes, the CSS works perfect when not fetched via AJAX.

Comment: @roasted What do you mean?

Comment: Would this have any effect on it?: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: try using a relative path like `url:"loadthis.php"`, and add `.fail()` to see if the request could be sent.

Comment: @spokey tried, results still same. No fail requests.

Comment: do u mind to use jQuery ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "success" option of ajax function,
take off the done function and insert the function in success option in ajax object,
like this:

```
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://example.com/loadthis.php",
        dataType: "html" ,
        success: function(result){
            $('ul.loadhere').html(result);      
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){
            ajax();
            function ajax(){
                $.get('loadthis.php', {}, function(){

                }).done(function(result){
                    $('ul.loadhere').html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```