# Can't use returned list from ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a list with an AJAX call to a C# method and display its items with jQuery, but I'm not able to do it. Here is what I got:

```
public string test()
{
    return "test ok";            
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Computer/test",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

This works as expected and i get an alert with 'test ok' string. However if i try to return a list i'm unable to traverse it in jquery.

```
public List<string> testList()
{
    List<string> test = new List<string>;
    test.Add("test1");
    test.Add("test2");
    return test;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Computer/testList",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var list = data.d;
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            alert(item);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);               
    }
});
```

With this code I get the following error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Json` on server side with `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, check out the reason why we have to use `JsonRequestBehavior` at [Why is JsonRequestBehavior needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed):

```
public JsonResult testList()
{
    List<string> test = new List<string>;
    test.Add("test1");
    test.Add("test2");
    return Json(test,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Computer/testList",
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(data){
   var list = data;
   $.each(list, function (index, item) {
       alert(item);
   });
})
.fail(function(xhr){
    alert(xhr.responseText); 
});
```

`success` and `error` are deprecated, use `.done` and `fail` instead

Comment: He is using settings object and defines properties success and error. Those are not deprecated. What is deprecated are methods jqXHR.success() and jqXHR.error() on jqXHR object. This is a return value of `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Lost_Cause: yes, I think I need to reword that. `.done` is prefered to `success`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller action to return Json:

```
public JsonResult testList()
{
    List<string> test = new List<string>;
    test.Add("test1");
    test.Add("test2");
    return Json(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a return type of `ActionResult` that returns JSON data via the `Json()` method, like this:

```
public ActionResult testList()
{
    List<string> test = new List<string>;
    test.Add("test1");
    test.Add("test2");

    return Json(test);
}
```

Note: In your jQuery `.ajax()` call you will not need the `data.d` syntax anymore either, so your jQuery will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Computer/testList",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var list = data;
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            alert(item);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);               
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use JsonResult in your C# code. JsonResult are more reliable here in ASP.NET MVC to return the data.

Simply use dictionary in c# to return collection of KeyValuePair