# JQuery - Break out of $.each

Tags: jquery, loops, break

I am trying to break out the following loop when I have retrieved 10 items from `data`:

```
var counter = 1;

$.ajax({
        url:'http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getchainstorelist?key=' + apiCode,
        dataType:'jsonp',           
        success: function(data){

        //create drop-down box
        var s = $('<select/>',{id:"chainStores"});

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            $('<option/>', {text: value.name}).appendTo(s);

            ++counter;

            // After finding 10 stores, break.
            if (counter == 10)
                return false;           
    });
```

However, it doesn't seem to be stopping after getting 10 items. It seems to be retrieving everything. I initially tried using `break` but received a syntax error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is your counter incrementing - I thought it should be `counter++;`

Comment: @Pete: That wouldn't make an observable difference for that particular line of code.

Comment: ah ok, learnt something today then!

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't modifying `counter`, or that the conditional statement is being evaluated at all?  `return false;` seems to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/yLBd7/

Comment: I'm with David - as counter seems to be global it could start off over 10 if something else uses a var called counter which would mean that == 10 never equates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious to me what is wrong in your code but you don't need a counter because you have already `key` in your function, which represents the index of the `array` in the loop and you are setting `counter = 1` but it starts from `0`. If you run [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/tjMjq/1/),

```
var data = [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if (key == 3) {
        console.log('Terminated...');
        return false;           
    }
    console.log(key);
});
```

Result will be

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> Terminated...

So, your code should work but the problem is in somewhere else. In you case, you may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tjMjq/3/) instead

```
var s = $('<select/>',{ id:"chainStores" } );
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('<option/>', {value:val.value, text: val.name}).appendTo(s);
    if (key >= 9) return false;           
});
$('body').append(s); // append to the body
```

Also, notice the `value` attribute in `options`, that you probably skipped or forgot.

Comment: Thanks RCV. This worked... There must have been something up with my `counter` variable. It's strange, because `counter` was not altered anywhere else in this file...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a counter. You can [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array to the max length you need.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getchainstorelist?key=' + apiCode,
    dataType:'jsonp',           
    success: function(data) {
        var s = $('<select/>',{id:"chainStores"});
        data = (data.length > 10) ? data.splice(0,10) : data;
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('<option/>', {text: value.name}).appendTo(s);
        });
});
```

Comment: @JanDvorak he likely already has a `<select>` tag with the id `chainStores` in the DOM and is just adding more and more options when he thinks it should be cleared each time.

Comment: @JanDvorak on second thought. I have no idea. I would just tell him `this isn't the bug you think is the bug`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getchainstorelist?key=' + apiCode,
    dataType:'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
    //create drop-down box
    var s = $('<select/>',{id:"chainStores"});
    $(data).slice(0,10).each(function(key, value) {
        $('<option/>', {text: value.name}).appendTo(s);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done