# $.get(link, function(r) vs $.get(link).done(function(r) vs $.get(link).success(function(r)

Tags: jquery

Which is the fastest in terms of milliseconds to get results from the page being loaded?
`$.get(link, function(r) { });` or `$.get(link).done(function(r) { });` or `$.get(link).success(function(r) { });`

Comment: I believe you won't get any measurable difference, but you can find out for yourself here: http://jsperf.com/. Note that the last one (`success`) is *deprecated*.

Comment: I feel like this question is ambiguous. The time it takes to load information is based on the server's processing of whatever request you send to it via the `$.get()` method. If the query is static, then I imagine that perhaps the first one will be the fastest as the 'success' function is given immediately, instead of deferred to the promise object given the `$.get(link)`. Also, I don't think there should be any difference between `.done()` and `.success`, to the best of my current knowledge, `done` is just the current version of the deprecated `success`.

Comment: so would `.done` be the best option?

Comment: performance difference is negligible, instead choose over each other based on other stuff. read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done