# How to alert message about file upload(using ajax) completition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I use following form to file upload:

```
<form method="POST"  action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageUploadForm">
               <input type="file" class="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```

and following ajax to send content to server.

```
$('.file').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('#imageUploadForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadImage',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        success: alertSucces,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

function alertSucces(){
    alert("success");
}
```

I see alert "success" as soon as I clicked on button. Expected result - see this message as soon as file will load on server.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Answer (score 1):

You should read about ajax document from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) first

After the upload is finished it should have a return message like "upload complete" and this message should be handled in your ajax function like :

```
success : function(data){
 if(data == "upload complete"){
  alert("success");
 }
}
```