# abort or mark an ajax request once the browser receive 200ok

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have the following request

```
// =============================================== start()
//
// clicked_button : the user click the start button.
// app_path       : the app path
//
// return none.
//
var start = function(clicked_button, app_path) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'app_path': app_path },
        url: '/app/start',
        context: clicked_button,
    })

    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).text('stop');
    })

    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log('failed to start the app: ' + data);
    })
};
```

the request is sent to the server, and the operation is done completely, *i've tested it*, the browser receive 200 OK, *i've check it*, but somehow the code in .done function is not executed, it's like the request is not completed yet.

how can i check if the browser receive a 200 ok, then just abort the ajax call, and continue the jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do that.

You can just use the success function in ajax.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'app_path': app_path },
        url: '/app/start',
        context: clicked_button,
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
           $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
           $(this).text('stop');
        },
        error: function(data){
           console.log('failed to start the app: ' + data);
        }
    })
```

Try this code and check out you firebug for any problem!

Comment: I was about to recommend the same, then I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done This says, that done is the preferred way. (Although I don't know why isn't it working)

Comment: i've used it, still the same, the browser does receive a 200 OK, the server side operation is completed successfuly, the data is updated, but the code inside success or done is not executed.

Comment: the code is available on github, please any ideas can be helpful https://github.com/oussamaelgoumri/appRunner/blob/master/app/eo/src/js/app.js

Comment: Check out in firebug how is the server responding to you. Are you printing your data after you update it on the server ??

Comment: @IdealBakija yes the server is responding, there is no data print, but all the php code is executed, please refer to the link in my previous comment to gain more insight about what am trying to do.

Comment: Well if you are not printing the data on the server neither the done command nor the success command will execute. Just write 'echo true'(if your are using php) in the end of your server Code. This will force your ajax to call the above actions. Let me know if it helps you!

Comment: @IdealBakija i've debugged the code, and i think the problem is because am using proc_open(), the test is working fine, the process is started, but the  request is pending, take a look at the App.inc.php class, the method is called start() https://github.com/oussamaelgoumri/appRunner/blob/master/app/eo/App.inc.php

Comment: @Oussama ELGOIMRI.. I have looked up at your code. I see you have in two places a 'return false'. That will stop the action and will not return an answer to ajax making it unable to call the Success or the Done action. Try to print 'echo true' instead of return false just to test if it will call the ajax. I am sorry I delayed the answer. I am a little busy once I find some free time I will try the code myself if you don't come up with a solution

Comment: @IdealBakija did you see my answer above, i know its not correct, but at least it does the trick, i don't know why the ajax is not received once done, i intentialy redirected all the output to /dev/null, but yet, nothing ... please review the code, and tel me what you think

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType: 'json' in order to get server response

Comment: i don't request any data from the server, i just have to execute some php code.

Comment: Then use to get api response url: '/app/start',

Comment: thank you for helping me, i've mentioned above how i solved this problem, do you have any idea how can improve my solution?

Comment: After ajax request you can use .done(function() { });

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by adding these lines to my php code:

```
sleep(1);
return Redirect::home();
```

why ?

after debugging the code, it look like all the operations that i request are completed, so the only problem is that the request is pending, or lost its way back, somehow ..

my best suggestion is because am using proc_open on my code ..

still not the best solution, but it is working and am half happy.