# What is AJAX best practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn javascript best practices and I am a bit confused. I have red that best ajax practice is:

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2) {  
    jQuery.ajax({
        var urlink = resourceURL
        url: urlink,
        cache: false,
        data : "testData"+arg1,
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        updateHtml1(obj);
        updateHtml2(obj);
    });
}
```

and not this way:

```
function getSomething(arg1, arg2) { 
    jQuery.ajax({
        var urlink = resourceURL
        url: urlink,
        cache: false,
        data : "testData"+arg1,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            updateHtml1(obj);
            updateHtml2(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

I am asking which practice is best and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Comment: The self-invoking function in the first example (and the question itself) doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Vohuman sorry, I fixed it

Comment: The first one is preferred. `$.ajax` returns a promise object. You can store the returned the value in a variable and call all the promise methods on it. It also makes your code more readable/maintainable.

Comment: You may also be interested in reading: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/24-best-practices-for-ajax-implementations--net-9180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way is fine, it's just a difference in using the `success` callback or a promise, and in this case there is no difference. If you would want to return the result from the function `doSomething` then you would use the first method so that you can return the promise, as the `done` method then can be bound outside the function.

Both examples are overly complicated, and the `var urlink = resourceURL` is placed inside an object literal, so neither would actually work. You should also specify the `dataType` in the call, then the data will be parsed automatically.

In the first example you don't need an extra function wrapper.

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2) {  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: resourceURL,
    cache: false,
    data : "testData"+arg1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    updateHtml1(data);
    updateHtml2(data);
  });
}
```

And the second should be:

```
function getSomething(arg1, arg2) { 
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: resourceURL,
    cache: false,
    data : "testData"+arg1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      updateHtml1(data);
      updateHtml2(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Although both are supported, the `jqXHR.success()` method has been deprecated — checking for the `.done()` promise would be the better way.

Comment: @Terry: There `jqXHR.success` method isn't used in either of the examples.