# Difference between a jQuery's .done(function() {}) and a success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there are difference between a `.done(function {})` and a `success` function in an `$.ajax` call? I need the one that doesn't permit the program to continue until the ajax call and the success function are complete. Does `.done(function {})` wait until success is completely processed or just continues as soon as the data is returned?

Comment: To do an async ajax call with jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re?rq=1

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done