# Why are these .getJSON and .ajax functions behaving differently?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to load a remote json file asynchronously. I've just spent a long time trying to debug the function that I expected to work. I'm still relatively new to JS, and would like to understand why teh following occurs.

The function I expected to work returns `undefined`.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: $url
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log( data );
});
```

Whereas this function returns the expected json object

```
$.getJSON( $url, function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I thought these functions are equivalent. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a wrong attribute in the ajax method. type is meant to be GET, POST, etc. but you are setting it up to json.

*"type is an alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0."*

For that to be correct, you need to set the dataType to 'json' and everything should fall in place. You can read more about ajax API on [jQuery Docs site](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: so, is it still undefined after the dataType change?

Comment: Yes, it is still undefined

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery 3.1.0

Comment: would you please update the data you are reading from the server? console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: $url,
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log( data );
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks @daniel, what is the difference between `success` and the `done` callback?

Comment: Let me refer you to this link for explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done