# jQuery Deferred's done vs success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Are there any technical differences between the following callback methods?

#### 1

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    foo(data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    bar();
  }
});
```

#### 2

```
$.ajax(...)
  .done(function(data) {
    foo(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    bar();
  });
```

#### 3

```
$.ajax(...)
  .then(function(data) {
    foo(data);
  }, function() {
    bar();
  });
```

With little experience, I am not sure they are correct examples for passing `data` to `foo()`. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

With `done`/`fail`, we can't track other data like `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, `errorThrown`, etc. Am I right?

Is there a `complete` equivalence for the `done`/`fail` method?

From your experience, is one better than/preferred over the others at certain situations?

If I use both `success` and `done`/`then`, will one run before the other definitely or it can't be certain which will run before the other definitely? Or is using `success` and `done`/`then` altogether not recommended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: "success:" vs ".done"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done)

Comment: `.then()` returns a new promise for chaining.  `.done()` does not.  `.then()` is closer to the promise standard (in JQ 3.0 it is actually standard, not fully in prior versions).  `.done()` is entirely a jQuery specific design and is not governed by any promise standard.

Answer (score 1):

One difference between jQuery [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done) and `.then()` is the return value can be changed at `.then()`

See [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done)

```js
$.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  dfd.resolve(1)
})
.done(function(n) {
  return n + 1
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res) // 1
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```js
$.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  dfd.resolve(1)
})
.then(function(n) {
  return n + 1
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res) // 2
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```