# javascript callback is not called when using ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

i have ajax call inside my function make it reusable, when my ajax success i want to callback a function,

```
var ajaxPostCall = function(data , url ,callback){
  // Return the $.ajax promise
$.ajax({
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function() {
        onStartAjaxRequest();
    },
    success:function(data){
        if(typeof callback == "function"){
            callback();  
        }else{
            console.log('not callback');
        }               
    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        onEndAjaxRequest();
    }
});
}

var ajaxGetCall = function(data , url ,callback){
  // Return the $.ajax promise
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function() {
        onStartAjaxRequest();
    },
    success:function(data){
        //console.log('test');
        if(typeof callback == "function"){
            callback();  
        }else{
            console.log('not callback');
        }          
    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        onEndAjaxRequest();
    }
   });
 }


function onStartAjaxRequest(){
    $('#spinner').hide();
}


function onEndAjaxRequest(){
        $('#spinner').show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
data = {'name' : 'john'};

function callbackSuccess(){
    console.log('success');
}

ajaxPostCall(data , '/proccess.php' , function(){
    console.log('success 1');
});

ajaxGetCall(data , '/proccessGet.php?id=12' , function(){
    console.log('success 2');
}); 

})
```

when i run this code, both of ajax post and get can work.but why only my ajaxget can call the callback 'success2' , the ajaxpost doesnt show 'success1' .. any idea?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1dkG.png)

Comment: On your post, add an error handler and see what is complaining about. 
error: function(data) {
         
      }

Comment: Apologies if not related, but use `done` rather than `success` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Comment: Are you sure your server responds with datatype `json`? If I use your `get` request, with url `https://api.github.com/zen`, and change the type to `text` it works.

Comment: `callback(); ` where is that function?

Comment: And FYI `/proccess.php` only one c in process :)

Comment: @pokeybit ops i knew it...my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i just find out myself and i know the problem...my `proccess.php` on ajaxpost is not returning json object properly , meanwhile i put `dataType: 'json'` in my ajaxpost, thats why my ajaxpost is not going to success callback

but i still wonder on my ajaxget still going to success callback even my  `/proccessGet.php?id=12` does not return json object , is ajax with `GET`method ignoring `datatype:json`?