# Javascript redirect in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is a continuation from my question last night. I have a JQuery AJAX response, as below. I just need this to redirect to another view. See my code:

```
      $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PersistSelections",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedItems),


            done: function (response) {
                window.location.href = "Home/GoToBooking";
            }
        })
```

The code in done, does not seem to work. I have also tried success. I'm also not sure what the parameter should be (response, or something else?).

In addition, I have seen code like this:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'");'
```

I have `JavascriptResult` resolving in my controllers, but when I try to use `return Javascript`, I can't seem to resolve the references? I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing -

```
    done: function (response) {
        window.location.href = "Home/GoToBooking";
    }
```

With -

```
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = "/Home/GoToBooking";
        }
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work. I added an alert to the body of the success call, but that does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

In controller instead of JavascriptResult Use IActionResult

In Js Use like this

```
$.ajax({
url: '//',
type: 'POST',
async: false,
data: { Your data },
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to be sure that the return data type is json because you set `dataType:"json"` in ajax.

Then `done` method should be used like below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/PersistSelections",
        /....
     })
         .done(function (response) {
            window.location.href = "/Home/GoToBooking";
     })
```

Referece:[jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: "success:" vs ".done"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840315/11398810)

Finally,the href should be `/Home/GoToBooking`.

Here is a working sample you could refer to:

1.View:

```
<button onclick="test()">click</button>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function test() {
        var selectedItems = { Id: 1, Namea: "aaa" };
         $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PersistSelections",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedItems)
         })
             .done(function (response) {
                window.location.href = "/Home/GoToBooking";
         })
    }
</script>
}
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersistSelections([FromBody]Test test)
{
    return new JsonResult(test);
}
```