# Deserialize JSON string for list to c# object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with .netcore asp.net project using C# jquery ajax json, I passed model from ajax call and received data(formdata) in string format but not be able to convert data of EmployeesList from string object to list object.

*ajax code*

```
$('#bttn_Click').click(function () {
                debugger;                
                var empListVal = null;
                empListVal = [];
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    empListVal .push($(this).attr('value'));
                });
                var Emp_des_ViewModel = {
                    Designation: des_Value,
                    Department: dep_Value,                    
                    EmployeesList: empListVal 
                };                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",                    
                    data: "formData=" + JSON.stringify(Emp_des_ViewModel),
                    url: '/Emp_Designation_Assign/InsertDesignation',
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                        window.location.href = "/Emp_Designation_Assign/InsertDesignation";
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

*Emp_des_ViewModel.cs*

```
public class Emp_des_ViewModel 
    {
        public string Designation{ get; set; }
        public string Department{ get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> EmployeesList{ get; set; }
    }
```

*Emp_Designation_AssignController.cs*

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult InsertDesignation(string formData)
    {
       var formdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(formData);
       Emp_des_ViewModel emp_desViewModel = new Emp_des_ViewModel();
       emp_desViewModel = (Emp_des_ViewModel)formdata;
       //other code

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to manually deserialize the request. If the JSON string actually matches the DTOs you can change the signature to `InsertDesignation(Emp_des_ViewModel emp_desViewModel)`. If it doesn't, manual deserialization won't work either. The code you posted is definitely wrong though. You can't just cast an arbitrary object to a different type. If you used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Emp_des_ViewModel>`(formData)` you'd get the object you want.

Comment: What does the JSON string look like?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your ajax should look like this

```
$('#bttn_Click').click(function () {
            debugger;                
            var empListVal = null;
            empListVal = [];
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                empListVal .push($(this).attr('value'));
            });
            var Emp_des_ViewModel = {
                Designation: des_Value,
                Department: dep_Value,                    
                EmployeesList: empListVal 
            };                
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",           
                contentType: 'application/json',         
                data: JSON.stringify(Emp_des_ViewModel),
                url: '/Emp_Designation_Assign/InsertDesignation'
                }).done(function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    window.location.href = "/Emp_Designation_Assign/InsertDesignation";
                    console.log(result);
            });
        });
```

Avoid using `success` and use `.done()` instead. I'm not the best person to explain why, so look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done) for further details.
In your controller, you can do this

```
public IActionResult InsertDesignation([FromBody]Emp_des_ViewModel formData)
{
   Emp_des_ViewModel emp_desViewModel = formdata;
   //other code
}
```

.Net will handle deserializing automatically for you, if JSON is compatible with your model.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes here:

1. The correct way to deserialize the json string to model should be(BTW, As other communities said, **no need deserialize** the json **manually**, just send model and the default model binding system will help you deserialize to model):

   ```
   var formdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Emp_des_ViewModel>(formData);
   ```
2. `EmployeesList` in your model is type of `List<SelectListItem>`, you could check the source code of `SelectListItem` below, it
   contains `Disabled`,`Group`,`Selected`,`Text` and `Value`
   properties:

   ```
   public class SelectListItem
   {              
       public SelectListItem();

       public SelectListItem(string text, string value, bool selected);

       public SelectListItem(string text, string value, bool selected, bool disabled);

       public bool Disabled { get; set; }

       public SelectListGroup Group { get; set; }

       public bool Selected { get; set; }

       public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   So you need send the data like below:

   ```
   empListVal.push({ "PropertyName": "CheckedValue1" }, {"PropertyName":"CheckedValue2"});
   ```

   In your code it may should be:

   ```
   empListVal .push({ "PropertyName":$(this).attr('value')});
   ```
3. If you must insist on sending json(`empListVal .push($(this).attr('value'));`) in your past way, you need change
   your model:

   ```
   public class Emp_des_ViewModel
   {
       public string Designation { get; set; }
       public string Department { get; set; }
       public List<string> EmployeesList { get; set; }
   }
   ```

**A whole working demo** you could follow:

1. Model:

   ```
   public class Emp_des_ViewModel
   {
       public string Designation { get; set; }
       public string Department { get; set; }
       public List<SelectListItem> EmployeesList { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. View:

   ```
   <button type="button" id="bttn_Click">click</button>
   @section Scripts
       {
       <script>
           $('#bttn_Click').click(function () {
               debugger;
               var empListVal = null;
               empListVal = [];
               empListVal.push({ "Value": "emp1" }, { "Value": "emp2" });
               var Emp_des_ViewModel = {
                   Designation: "aaa",
                   Department: "bbb",
                   EmployeesList: empListVal
               };
               $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   data: JSON.stringify(Emp_des_ViewModel),
                   url: '/Emp_Designation_Assign/InsertDesignation',
                   datatype: "json",
                   success: function (result) {
                       //...
                   }
               });
           });
       </script>
   }
   ```
3. Controller:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult InsertDesignation([FromBody]Emp_des_ViewModel formData)
   {
       //other code
       return Json(formData);
   }
   ```