# how to enter dynamic data to a javascript function after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select box which options are coming from database depending on another selected option using ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.entity").change(function(){
        var selectedEntity = $(".entity option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "entityName.php",
            data: { entity : selectedEntity } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#entityName").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

// This is the select box where options are dynamic.

```
<label>Select Entity Name:</label>
<select id="entityName" name="entityName" class="select_box" required>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type First</option>
</select>
```

This works fine but now i want a search box for the options. I am using this function for search.

```
var select_box_element = document.querySelector('.select_box');
dselect(select_box_element, {
        search: true
       });
```

As options are dynamic and loaded after the page load that's why this function doesnot work.

I need to push dynamic options into dselect function based on the selection.

Comment: What is dselect?

Comment: JavaScript library that adds advanced features (like live search, dynamic creation, field validation)

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] - you can make an example adata object since the ajax works right?

Comment: I cannot seem to find a dselect cdn. Is it this one? https://dselect.vercel.app/

Comment: @mplungjan yes.

Comment: What is the format of `data` you're receiving in your AJAX response? Also, have you tried simply filling the `.select_box` with your response, and then initializing your `dselect` in the AJAX `.done`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you. I've used CSS and JS for the dselect library, as shown in [the official GitHub repo](https://github.com/jarstone/dselect). In the example, Bootstrap 5 files are also included, since dSelect seems to be relying on Bootstrap 5 files.

The API used is from the free [Pokemon API](https://pokeapi.co).

Some notes on the slight rewriting on how the AJAX is handled:

- no need to call the AJAX, if there's nothing inside the first `select` element, and if we revert to the default `#entityType` value. We just need to clear the previous contents of the `#entityName`. That is what the `if` does right inside the `change` event handler
- the AJAX call contains a predefined `dataType` attribute. This was done because I know in advance that the `response` in my example (response of Pokemon API) will be in JSON format. You can also do that in your specific case, if you control the back-end / the way `entityName.php` works and outputs its results. If you don't have that kind of control, you may want to omit this AJAX config parameter, and handle the results differently
- instead of using `$.ajax({...}).done(...)`, the example uses separate `success` and `error` handlers. This was just a preference choice. For differences between the use of `success` and `done`, please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840315). In your specific case, `.done(...)` would have worked as well, with additional testing if the received `data` matches what you expect it to match, like this:

```
$.ajax({
// your ajax setup
}).done(function(data){
  if(data) {
      $("#entityName").html(data);
  } else {
      $("#entityName").html('<option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type First</option>');
  }

  dselect($("#entityName")[0], { search: true });
});
```

- the example also uses `config`, as shown in the official GitHub repo. Again, if you're happy with the way you're initializing your `dselect`, you can skip the configuration

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const config = {
        search: false, // Toggle search feature. Default: false
        creatable: false, // Creatable selection. Default: false
        clearable: false, // Clearable selection. Default: false
        maxHeight: '360px', // Max height for showing scrollbar. Default: 360px
        size: '', // Can be "sm" or "lg". Default ''
    }
    dselect($("#entityName")[0], config);

    $("#entityType").change(function(){
        let entityType = $(this).val();
        if(!entityType) {
          $("#entityName").html('<option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type First</option>');
          dselect($("#entityName")[0], config);
          return false;
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/" + entityType,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              let pokemon = data.pokemon;
              let pokeList = '<option value="" selected>Please choose your Pokemon</option>';
              console.log(pokemon[0].pokemon.name);
              for(var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
                let pokeName = pokemon[i].pokemon.name;
                let pokeUrl = pokemon[i].pokemon.url;

                pokeList += '<option value="' + pokeUrl + '">' + pokeName + '</option>';
              }
              
              $("#entityName").html(pokeList);
              dselect($("#entityName")[0], config);
            },
            error: function(desc, err) {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(desc) + ", " + JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#entityType {
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@jarstone/dselect/dist/css/dselect.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@jarstone/dselect/dist/js/dselect.js"></script>
<label for="entityType">Select Entity Type:</label>
<select id="entityType" name="entityType" class="select_box" required>
     <option value="">Choose</option>
     <option value="water">Water</option>
     <option value="fire">Fire</option>
     <option value="ground">Ground</option>
     <option value="electric">Electric</option>
     <option value="flying">Flying</option>
</select>
<select id="entityName" name="entityName" class="select_box" required>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type First</option>
</select>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. could you please explain why you used [0] with deselect()

Comment: @Tanvir:  I used [0] (and FiddlingAway took it over) to use the DOM element from jQuery object. You (and dselect) uses a DOM element as parameter, I chose to use jQuery to get the element and then pass the DOM version to the function since I did not have time or access to dselect to figure out if dselect could take a jQUery object

Comment: thanks for the explanation. your example is a bit complicated and not the way i am looking for. search should be in the option list not separated.

Comment: @Tanvir If you use `$(<selector>)`, you could think of it as getting an array of DOM elements, like you would with `document.querySelectorAll(<selector>)`. With vanilla (regular) Javascript, when using `document.querySelectorAll(...)`, you extract a specific DOM element of those you collected, by passing an array index - for example, if you have three buttons in your DOM, and you use `document.querySelectorAll("button")`, you would get the first one with `document.querySelectorAll("button")]0]`. The same thing applies to jQuery - since `$("#entityName")` is an array of DOM elements, using ->

Comment: -> `$("#entityName")[0]` takes the first (and the only) element from that array, which we can then pass to `dselect` as a specific DOM element on which we want to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I use `$("#entityName")[0]` to get at the DOM element from the jQuery Object

```
}).done(function(data){
  $("#entityName").html(data);
  dselect($("#entityName")[0], { search: true });
});
```

Example - you need to add some CSS I think

```js
const $select_box_element = $('#entityName');
const $entity = $('#entityType');
$("select.entity").change(function(){
  if (this.value === "one") {
    $select_box_element.html(`<option value="one">One</option><option value="oneone">OneOne</option>`)
    dselect($select_box_element[0], { search: true });
  }
  else {
    $select_box_element.html(`<option value="two">Two</option><option value="twotwo">TwoTwo</option>`)
    dselect($select_box_element[0], { search: true });
  }
});

dselect($entity[0], { search: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@jarstone/dselect/dist/css/dselect.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@jarstone/dselect/dist/js/dselect.js"></script>
<label>Select Entity Type:</label>
<select id="entityType" name="entityType" class="entity" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
<label>Select Entity Name:</label>
<select id="entityName" name="entityName" class="select_box" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Entity Type First</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the ans. this is what i am looking for but your example is misleading.

Comment: It is identical to what you accepted but was posted 45 minutes later! What is misleading?